# event change for enumdropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In view

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Field)
```

Model

```
public Fields Field { get; set; }

public enum Fields
{
    First = 1,
    Second
}
```

These my markup

```
<select id="Field" name="Field">
    <option selected="selected" value="1"> First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

These script dont call

```
$('select#Field').change(function () {
    var orderIdd = $('#Field').val();
    alert(orderIdd);
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @enigma `These scripts dont call` :)

Comment: what error do you have in console?

Comment: Is the script wrapped in `document.ready()` or at the bottom of the page. Do you have `jquery-{version}.js` included?

Comment: @Backs without errors

Comment: @StephenMuecke in the bottom. yes I have

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nwma85a2/ - works, you forget something

Comment: @Backs I dont see changes

Comment: no changes, it's your code and it works. so,  try ro debug your client code

Comment: does your browser allow javascript? :)

Comment: Yes. others scripst are run. But it doesnt run

Answer (score 0):

Try following things:

In your view; change declaration like this:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Field,"Select..." ,new { @class="fields-select"})
```

And update your javascript code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.fields-select').change(function () {
        var orderIdd = $(this).val();
        alert(orderIdd);
    });
});
```

May be Id which is getting generated for `select` is different other than `id="Field"` in your case.

Comment: can you try putting `.change()` code inside `$(document).ready`. Also check your generated HTML via firebug or browser's inspect element and see what `id` and `class` is getting assigned to your enum select box.

Comment: Yes. I tried. I checked. Id is correct. In console I can call to $('select#Field'). But I dont uderstand why event doesnt appear

Comment: Just last try: please do this:  `new { @class="fields-select", @onchange = "onSelectChange(this);} ` and put some alert in newly created `function onSelectChange(obj)`. Check whether that work or not. If it does, then move your above code into this new function.

Comment: Yes. It works. But why this case is working? Although others arent

Comment: This is really strange and I am also thinking why other cases are failing